# How do I add annotations to a chart in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, annotations, ios-charts

I am using iOS Charts (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) to visualize some data sets. I want to be able to add annotations to specific points of the chart.

I originally did this using SciChart due to their annotations feature, but had to switch to Charts due to budgetary constraints. Haven't been able to figure out how to replicate the annotations portion of the project using Charts.

For example if I were to add "test annotation" to the point [1,1], the text would be placed onto the chart at point [1,1].

In short: I want to figure out how to create a single annotation object containing text and place it onto the chart at a specified point.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I was able to find a solution. Thought I would share incase it helps anyone else!

I added the Balloon Marker class included with the Charts files on GitHub (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Swift/Components/BalloonMarker.swift) to my project.

Then I went inside the class and modified a snippet of the code:

```
open override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)
    {
        setLabel(String(entry.y))
    }
```

to

```
    open override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)
    {
        let des = entry.data as! String
        let annot = "X: " + String(entry.x) + "\n Y:" + String(entry.y) + "\n Annotation: " + des
        setLabel(annot)
    }
```

With the difference being that the original only had the marker display the Y coordinate and my modified code snippet now showing the X, Y, and data fields of the ChartDataEntry object.

With that done I had my annotations working on the graph,

TL;DR:

- Set fields for ChartDataEntry object
- Modify BM class to display the relevant fields